# What is the weka equivalent to caret's rfe?

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka, feature-selection, rfe

I am working with weka and have to perform an attribute selection on my dataset. A former coworker did this once with rfe from the caret package of R. What would be the equivalent function to rfe in weka? I am no statistician, so maybe this question sounds oddly, but I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ClassifierSubsetEval` as Attribute Evaluator along with `BestFirst` search method, setting the direction of the search to `Backward`.

Comment: George Dontas Thank you! I read about the methods you mentioned and already used `BestFirst` with `Forward` setting. I was unable to understand what the rfe from caret does, since I cannot yet code in R. Does that mean, that  similar to `ClassifierSubsetEval`,  rfe can use several different classifying algorithms for the attribute selection?

Comment: The web page http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/ has details and examples related to this function. See also here http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/caret/html/rfe.html